# Webdriver PageObject Implementation using PageFactory in Java

Tags: webdriver, pageobjects

here is what i have so far:

A working Webdriver based Java class, which logs-in to the application and goes to a Home page:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class MLoginFFTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private String fileName = "screenshot.png";

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("network.http.phishy-userpass-length", 255);
        profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);

        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

        baseUrl = "https://a.b.c.d/";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccountLogin() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "web/certLogon.jsp");
        driver.findElement(By.name("logonName")).clear();

        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(driver.findElement(By.name("logonName"))
                .getTagName(), "input");

        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "DA Logon");

        driver.findElement(By.name("logonName")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Account")).click();


        AssertJUnit.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "View Account");


    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        try {
            FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(fileName));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Now as we see there are 2 pages:
1. Login page, where i have to enter username and password, and homepage, where i would be taken, once the authentication succeeds.

Now i want to implement this as PageObjects using Pagefactory: so i have :

```
package com.example.pageobjects;

import static com.example.setup.SeleniumDriver.getDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;



public abstract class MPage<T> {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://a.b.c.d/";
    private static final int LOAD_TIMEOUT = 30;
    private static final int REFRESH_RATE = 2;

    public T openPage(Class<T> clazz) {
        T page = PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), clazz);
        getDriver().get(BASE_URL + getPageUrl());
        ExpectedCondition pageLoadCondition = ((MPage) page).getPageLoadCondition();
        waitForPageToLoad(pageLoadCondition);
        return page;
    }

    private void waitForPageToLoad(ExpectedCondition pageLoadCondition) {
        Wait wait = new FluentWait(getDriver())
                .withTimeout(LOAD_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(REFRESH_RATE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
    }

    /**
     * Provides condition when page can be considered as fully loaded.
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected abstract ExpectedCondition getPageLoadCondition();

    /**
     * Provides page relative URL/
     *
     * @return
     */
    public abstract String getPageUrl();
}
```

And for login Page not sure how i would implement that, as well as the Test, which would call these pages.

Answer (score 1):

I hope these links will be helpful:

[page objects in webdriver](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/10/10/using-page-objects-with-selenium-and-web-driver-20/)

[page object using jBehave](http://jbehave.org/reference/web/stable/page-objects.html)

I would recommend having one class responsible for before/after methods and they should be than called before and after whole scenario. Right now you would close webdriver just after logging in to your page and I guess this is not desired beahaviour. You can extract one level of abstraction simply for Pages where all the clicking happens (right now your MLoginFFTest class does logging in) for both login page and main page.
Now the other class would simply run methods from your Pages calsses like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldOpenMainPage(){
   LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage();
   MainPage mainPage = loginPage.loginCorrectly();
   mainPage.verifyOnMainPage();
   mainPage.doSthElse();
   verifySth(....);
}
```

So now your file structure could be sth like

```
++pages/LoginPage.class
++pages/MainPage.class
++steps/SomeTest.class
```

Hope this helps.